# Can anyone recommend a Silverlight 2 book?

Tags: silverlight

Even though Silverlight2 is still in it's infancy, can anyone recommend a book to get started with? One that has more of a developer focus than a designer one?

Comment: As of now, there just aren't that many books available on this topic ... you might have better luck looking on the web.

Answer (score 3):

I have this one pre-ordered: "Programming Silverlight 2"
by Jesse Liberty and Tim Heuer. The authors are both employed by Microsoft working on Silverlight 2, and their blogs are great, so I expect the book (to be released after RTM) to be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some of the work done by Laurent... wait for his book

[image: Sams Silverlight 2 Unleashed]
<sub>(source: [galasoft.ch](https://galasoft.ch/blogs-all/2008090101.png))</sub>

[Sams Silverlight 2 Unleashed](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115155217/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2008/09/01/sams-silverlight-2-unleashed-was-teach-yourself-silverlight-in-24.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working my way through [Introducing Microsoft Silverlight 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562528X), so far so good.

It's a typical Microsoft book serving up the **koolaid**, but gives a good introduction.  I saw the guy speak at one of the local .NET User Groups in the Metro Detroit area and was impressed.

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YD6H7PQyL._SL500_BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-dp-500-arrow,TopRight,45,-64_OU01_AA240_SH20_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YD6H7PQyL._SL500_BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-dp-500-arrow,TopRight,45,-64_OU01_AA240_SH20_.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've started reading [Silverlight 2 in Action](http://www.manning.com/campbell/) which seems pretty ok. One good thing is that because they have an early access program, you can get most of the book as an electronic copy already now. Even though the full book is not due to be released until sometime in October.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the books available are simply a rehash of the help files. Your best bet would be to start at silverlight.net and read the Help files that get installed with the SDK. Then when Jesse Liberty's book is released read that.